# Why is my texture pink in material material preview, but not in rendered view?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I'm a beginner in Blender, and from my understanding, when a texure is pink it is because something is wrong with the file, or the reference to the file. However, my texture is showing in rendered view, but not in material preview. How can I fix this issue?

Material preview:
[image]

Render preview:
[image]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: solid view can have textures as well, you can see that bottom part has some texture and top is pink because texture is missing... providing your file would solve that, please don't forget to go to File > External Data >Pack all into .blend

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Nodes make sure the *Material Output* node is set to *All*.

The menu allows you to create shader variations depending on the active rendering engine, but if a material doesn't have an output for the current one it shows up as pink.

Comment: I am not sure why anyone gave you -1, this is the best possible solution in this case if we don't have his file, I am giving you +1

Comment: Doing this fixed my problem, thanks!